# Lucene search engine isn't accurate, can't figure out why

Tags: java, search, lucene, search-engine

I am trying to create a search engine for the first time, and I'm using the library offered by Apache Lucene. Everything works fine, however when I search for more than one word, for example "computer science" the results that I get aren't accurate because I never get documents that contain both words. It searches the documents for each word separately (I get documents that contain either "computer" or "science" but never both).

I've been staring at my code for almost a week now and I can't figure out the problem. The query parsing seems to work perfectly, so I think the problem might be in the search but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. So If you can help me, I'll be grateful.

```
    public static wikiPage[] index(String searchQuery) throws SQLException, IOException, ParseException {

    String sql = "select * from Record";
    ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);

    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

    //1. Indexer
    try (IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            String RecordID = rs.getString("RecordID");
            String URL = rs.getString("URL");
            String Title = rs.getString("Title");
            String Info = rs.getString("Info");

            addDoc(w, RecordID, URL, Info, Title);
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
        index.close();
    }

     //2. Query
    MultiFieldQueryParser multipleQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]{"Title", "Info"}, new StandardAnalyzer());
    Query q = multipleQueryParser.parse(searchQuery);


    //3. Search
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopDocs results = searcher.search(q, 10000);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;


    // 4. display results
    wikiPage[] resultArray = new wikiPage[hits.length];
    System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
    for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
        int docId = hits[i].doc;
        Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
        resultArray[i] = new wikiPage(d.get("URL"), d.get("Title"));
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("Title") + "\t" + d.get("URL"));
    }
    reader.close();
    return resultArray;
}

    private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String RecordID, String URL, String Info, String Title) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new StringField("RecordID", RecordID, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("Title", Title, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("URL", URL, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("Info", Info, Field.Store.YES));

    w.addDocument(doc);

}
```

This is the output of **System.out.println(q.toString());**

```
  (Title:computer Info:computer) (Title:science Info:science)
```

Comment: Can you show your query?  You might need to put the whole phrase in quotes *inside the query string*, or separate the words with the boolean operator AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search it as a phrase (that is, finding "computer" and "science" *together*), surround the query with quotes, so it should look like `"computer science"`.  In your code, you could do something like:

```
Query q = multipleQueryParser.parse("\"" + searchQuery + "\"");
```

If you just want to find docs that contain both terms *somewhere* in the document, but not necessarily together, the query should look like `+computer +science`.  Probably the easiest way to do this is to change the default operator of your query parser:

```
multipleQueryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
Query q = multipleQueryParser.parse(searchQuery);
```

Comment: The first method is what I'm aiming for and It worked, however some of the retrieved documents don't contain "computer science", "computer" or "science". Even though I am only searching the div tags and the webpages' titles. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @Sarah - Hard to say what the problem might be.  It's finding them *somewhere*.  You are printing the "Title" field, so I'm guessing you would notice a hit there.  Perhaps try printing the "Info" field, those hits might be coming from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will do what you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

As per the doc, prefix *required* terms with `+` and use `AND` (and `OR` for readability).

Try this:

```
(Title:+computer OR Info:+computer) AND (Title:+science OR Info:+science)
```

Maybe build this string and use it directly.

Comment: you mean I should put this string instead of the q query here: results = searcher.search(q, 10000); ?

Comment: @Sarah it's been a while since I used lucene, but I know the API allows you to use a raw string as your query (rather than using a builder).

Comment: The string needs to be parsed first for it to be query. So I don't think this method will work.

Comment: I don't believe this is valid query syntax.  `(Title:computer OR Info:computer) AND (Title:science OR Info:science)` (or alternatively `+(Title:computer Info:computer) +(Title:science Info:science)`) would be more correct, but kinda ignores that `MultiFieldQueryParser` is being used here.